# Use an alias in the same sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this sql query:

```
select GEN_source, count(*) as count, sum(100) / total as percentage
from tics
cross join (select count(*) as total from t_cs) x
group by 1
```

How to add the `order by count ASC` using the created alias in the same query ?

Thanks.

Comment: try using the `count` (with backtics ) instead. Generally order by alias must work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count is a reserved word so it needs to be encased on backtics or change the name

```
select GEN_source, count(*) as `count`, sum(100) / total as percentage
from tics
cross join (select count(*) as total from t_cs) x
group by 1
ORDER By `count`
```

or

```
select GEN_source, count(*) as cnt, sum(100) / total as percentage
from tics
cross join (select count(*) as total from t_cs) x
group by 1
ORDER By cnt
```